# Debug SplashScreen from Eclipse without generating the Jar

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, swing, splash-screen

I have search all over the web but could not find answer to this question:

I need to debug the functioning of an application that changes the SplashScreen based on the module you are accessing.

I do know that the code:

```
SplashScreen splash = SplashScreen.getSplashScreen();
```

Can be used to get the instance when you pass either:

- Splash from command line: java -splash:path/image.gif ClassFile
- Splash image in manifest: splashscreen-image: img/SplashNomina.gif

Still when I tried to run the application by passing the -splash value from VM args in Eclipse it did not work.

Is it actually possible as SplashScreen.getSplashScreen() is always NULL.
I have been trying passing without success:

- -splash:image.gif
- -Dsplash=image.gif

Right now I see lots of limitations in this Splash api, as it is always required to have a parameter being passed. I think it would be much more flexible to be able to just pass the parameter at runtime :(

Any help woult be really appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried _VM Arguments_ in your _Run Configuration_?

Comment: Yes, I have tried actually passing the arguments from there. It seems that the problem lies in that -splash:image argument relies on a file located withint he same directory and I am trying to include the image within the Jar file.

Comment: Sorry, I misread. You might also try this [utility](http://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/manifesto) to verify the `SplashScreen-Image` attribute _in situ_.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

OK, this has bitten me too.

I built a runnable jar 
with manifest entry

```
SplashScreen-Image: MyGraphic.jpg
```

and it works as it's supposed to.

From Eclipse, specifying the VM arg as

```
-splash:MyGraphic.jpg
```

no such luck

SplashScreen.getSplashScreen() returns null.

The reason for this is the brain-dead implementation of SplashScreen.getSplashScreen() in the JDK (at least 1.6).  I think.  It's kind of hard to tell without getting into what the native code is doing.  But, here is this method from java.awt.SplashScreen.  I'm not sure if it's called but studying it  did provide me with the essential clue I needed to get this working in Eclipse:

```
public synchronized URL getImageURL() throws IllegalStateException {
    checkVisible();
    if (imageURL == null) {
        try {
            String fileName = _getImageFileName(splashPtr);
            String jarName = _getImageJarName(splashPtr);
            if (fileName != null) {
                if (jarName != null) {
                    imageURL = new URL("jar:"+(new File(jarName).toURL().toString())+"!/"+fileName);
                } else {
                    imageURL = new File(fileName).toURL();
                }
            }
        }
        catch(java.net.MalformedURLException e) {
            // we'll just return null in this case
        }
    }
    return imageURL;
}
```

Note that in the case of a file (i.e. command-line rather than jar launch) it's not doing a getResource() to get the URL but opening a file relative to the CWD.  Since Eclipse run configurations default to running from the root of the project, the answer is to specify the path as a relative path and not to expect a classpath lookup.

Therefore, since I am building with maven, my image is located at src/main/resources/MyGraphic.jpg.  Specifying this as the command line parameter: i.e.

```
-splash:src/main/resources/MyGraphic.jpg
```

allows it to work in Eclipse (or, I guess, any command line)

I'm not sure WHY this is, since the getImageURL method is NOT called by getSplashScreen() but it DOES work.

To me this is kind of brain-dead on the part of Sun/Oracle.  They could have easily done a classpath lookup with something like
imageURL = getResource(filename) but they did not.

**The short answer is that the Splash Screen command line syntax refers to a filename relative to the current working direrctory, not relative to the classpath.**

Comment: Great analysis on this. Thanks for your effort to explain this matter, would still be on the dark without your answer. :)

Answer (score 4):

I'm answering 3 years later but I had the same problem and I tried to resolve.
I found the solution, and I think it would be useful to everybody.

You have to create a launch configuration, specifying in the *VM arguments* the parameter *-splash:image.gif*. This parameter refers to the root directory of the project (not /bin or /src). So you have to put your image in the same level as /bin and /src (or you can specify a different path in the -splash option).

When you export the runnable JAR from 'export' specifying the launch configuration you created  before, it says 'can't include VM arguments, you have to specify from command line' (and it doesn't include your image.gif in the root).
So if you want to have a runnable jar with your splash image, you can refer to another topic on stackoverflow which i'm not finding anymore. Someone answered that the best solution is FatJar. You can proceed as follows: export > other > fat jar exporter. Tick 'select manifest file', specifying a MANIFEST.MF containing 'SplashScreen-Image: splash.gif' (if you don't know how to create, deselect this checkbox, create a jar with the default one, modify the one created and include it). In the next page of the exportation, be sure to include your images in the jar with the 'add dir' button (it includes the content of the directory specified to the root directory of the project, so pay attention with the directory in the manifest).
It worked for me.

**So if you want to run with eclipse, add the splash image to the root directory and specify -splash:image.gif in the VM arguments. If you want to export a JAR, the FatJar plugin worked for me as I specified.**

I hope it helps :)

(sorry for my english, i'm not english :P)

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering, it does not matter if this was 3 year old question, as some people might be having this issue just right now and your contribution is very valuable!! :)

Answer (score 3):

Well guys, I decided yo go my independent way because the Splash class is too monolithic, so here I put my class:

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;


public class SplashWindow extends JFrame {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 9090438525613758648L;

  private static SplashWindow instance;

  private boolean paintCalled = false;

  private Image image;

  private SplashWindow(Image image) {
    super();
    this.image = image;
    JLabel label = new JLabel();
    label.setIcon(new ImageIcon(image));
    this.add(label);    
    this.setUndecorated(true);
    this.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
    this.pack();
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

  }

  public static void splash(URL imageURL) {
    if (imageURL != null) {
      splash(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(imageURL));
    }
  }

  public static void splash(Image image) {
    if (instance == null && image != null) {
      instance = new SplashWindow(image);
      instance.setVisible(true);

      if (!EventQueue.isDispatchThread() && Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors() == 1) {

        synchronized (instance) {
          while (!instance.paintCalled) {
            try {
              instance.wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void update(Graphics g) {
    paint(g);
  }

  @Override
  public void paint(Graphics g) {
    g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);
    if (!paintCalled) {
      paintCalled = true;
      synchronized (this) {
        notifyAll();
      }
    }
  }

  public static void disposeSplash() {
    instance.setVisible(false);
    instance.dispose();
  }
}
```

Hope it helps someone ;)